# An unsecured or incorrectly secured fault was received from the other party. Other questions not fixing problem

Tags: http, wcf

Looking at other answers to this question don't provide results.  The client and server are currently on the same machine so it isn't a sync issue (unless there is something else that is involved that I don't understand) and the username and password are verified correct.

I didn't design this setup. I was told to build it so telling me that this is stupid is preaching to the choir.  The system in question accepts a Https API call that it relays to a WCF service.  The WCF service verifies the credentials through a call to a stored procedure in a database and then performs the service.

When everything was on a single development machine, it worked.  I've moved it into a test environment where the API service and the WCF service are running on the same machine but the database is on a separate server. When I send the call from Postman into the HTTPS service, I get the error:

An unsecured or incorrectly secured fault was received from the other party.

Remoted debugging shows me getting to the point of the call of the service but no breakpoint is hit in the WCF service.

Don't know what code or configuration would be helpful to show so let me know and I'll update with specifics.

Comment: According to the error, we know that the transmission security of the service is at risk. You need to choose an authentication method to ensure its security, such as [basic authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/transport-security-with-basic-authentication) and [certificate authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/transport-security-with-certificate-authentication). You can try setting it up and see if there's anything else going on.